# Insert two or multiple query results in the same array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I am using wordpress code to query results from my database:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT pic0,bio,url,site,applet FROM ".$table." WHERE $condition"); // this code returns an array.
```

**Is there a way to merge two or multiple query results in the $query array?**

I have tried this:

```
$query = array();

$query = $wpdb->get_results("query 1");

$query = $wpdb->get_results("query 2");
```

And its not working.

Comment: It would overwrite. There should be some API in PHP's array to append. YOu should probably use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually pretty close, because you set `$query` again, you've actually overridden the variable, instead, you should **add** to it, there are 2 ways of doing so:

```
$query = array();

array_push($query, $wpdb->get_results("query 1"));

array_push($query, $wpdb->get_results("query 2"));
```

Or the shorter version:

```
$query = array();

$query[] = $wpdb->get_results("query 1");

$query[] = $wpdb->get_results("query 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge function as follow,

$query1Arr, $query2Arr

```
array_merge($query1Arr, $query2Arr);
```

Comment: I really need to learn php's basics, I am a webmaster but I somewhat feel ashamed to ask a question which has such an easy answer

Comment: But PHP has about 10,000 basics, right? You've contributed a useful question to the Stack Overflow community. Nice going.

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultSet = array_merge($wpdb->get_results("query 1"),
                         $wpdb->get_results("query 2"));
```